# Changing primitive bindings without losing them in scheme

Tags: scheme, key-bindings

For example, if i wanted to redefine addition as multiplication:

```
(define + *)
```

But *also* redefine multiplication as addition without losing the binding for addition, how could I do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the require mechanism that allow you to re-define standard procedures. These re-definitions are possible in Racket (R5RS implementations) in this way. You can require the standard + with a different name (standard+):

```
#lang racket
(require
 (rename-in racket/base (+ standard+))
 )
```

So you can re-define +  as a new one for your purposes

```
(define +
  (lambda args
    (if (not(null? args))
        (apply
         (cond
           (??? *)
           (else standard+))
         args)
        0)))
```

where ??? is your boolean condition (or just a function that return a boolean value) for the use of * instead of +.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple `let` which will bind things as they were defined before, regardless of other `let` definitions. In Gambit scheme:

```
> (* (+ 2 4) 2) ;; = 2 * (2 + 4)
12

> (let ((confusing #t)(+ *)(* +)) ;; Redefining operations
    (* (+ 2 4) 2))  ;; = 2 + (2 * 4)
10
```

Answer (score 0):

With import you can switch top level symbols in Scheme and it requires R6RS or later.

```
#!r6rs
(import (except (rnrs base) + *)
        (rename (rnrs base) (* +) (+ *)))

(+ (* 2 3) 4) ; ==> 20
```

You can also prefix import if you wan't to create your own language with the same symbols and need to access the original implementation symbols though some method:

```
#!r6rs
(import (prefix (rnrs base) base:))
(base:define * base:+)
(base:define + base:*)
(+ (* 2 3) 4) ; ==> 20
```

This answer is similar to Modestino's answer except their answer is for the racket language and not the scheme language.

Since this won't work with R5RS, you may want to look at [Valentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18870701/1565698), since it is a nice workaround. Just remember to have the let wrap the entire code and it will work as a R6RS renamed import.